# Socket Programming on a single computer?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am building a client-server chat application.

It has both a server and a client part.

Is it possible to test the application on the same machine or do i need really need two different computer to run the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to test your application on same machine.

IP Address of both client and server in this case would be same. Just open different ports for client and server.

Comment: Server will always listen on single constant port.. But each client will have to open a port (which can't be same as server) in order to communicate with server port.

Comment: Yeah sorry I deleted my comment, what I meant is that usually socket libraries automatically do that. I mean you only define the peer port and let socket randomly decide what port to use in order to "go out". Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

- Start your server up and it will listen to a specific port(The server application either has defined one or you have to provide one to it).
- Start the client application and make it connect to your machine (127.0.0.1) with the port number your server application listens to.

You may have to modify the application to change the IP address or port number if the program you have does not provide you command line options to specify them.

Answer (score 1):

You can test on the same machine. I am doing this right now as I type this note. :)

Of course normal things you would expect apply...you can't test two listeners on the same port which are on the same interface, for example. But a client connecting to a server on the same box should work no problem.

And of course before you release you should test on different machines as well. This could expose bugs that a single box config does not.

Answer (score 1):

no need, you can bind same IP and different port. they will work.
or you can install a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can test on the same machine, just make sure the the client and server bind to different ports.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can test it locally.  You can use the loopback address of `127.0.0.1` , your machine name or ip address to connect.

If you are selecting port numbers for your app, please make sure you understand what [ports are used and reserved](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt) for other programs.  For example, if you try and use port 80, you will run into conflicts with people who are running web servers.

Also, while testing locally is great, you need to make sure you understand how your app will need to be configured in different firewall applications and routers.